# how to get Claims value for identity Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I need to get Claims Value in the Controller. for this I get all claims and show in razor view:

```
@model List<IRSProject.Model.UserService.RoleClaimsViewModel>
    
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p class="font-weight-bold">@item.RoleName</p>
    
    @foreach (var Claim in item.Claims)
    {
        <p>@Claim.Type</p>
    }
}
```

and when create Checkbook list of Claims:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-4 col-role">
        <input type="checkbox" id=@item.RoleName>
        <span>@item.RoleName</span>
        <ul style="margin-left:1em">
            @foreach (var claim in item.Claims)
            {
                //This code is wrong!!!
                <li>@Html.EditorFor(m => claim.Type , "CheckBox")</li>           
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

RoleClaimsViewModel

```
public class RoleClaimsViewModel
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
}
```

how to get Claims value (True Or False) in Controller?

Comment: I suggest read more about identity in asp core. In controller ... context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "BadgeId") https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: What does "get Claims value (true or false) in Controller" mean? Since you can get it in the page, why not get it directly in the controller?